# Low framerate with near objects on Tegra device

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, tegra

I'm working on a small game using OpenGL ES2 on Android.

The game is running at 60FPS on many devices except one for the moment: A Wiko Highway 4G (A powerful smartphone with a Tegra 4i processor).

So, I've downloaded the "NVidia Tegra Android Development Pack" to find the bottleneck. The tools show me that my game take something like 40% on the processor, so I don't understand why the framerate was so low (20-25 FPS).

With some tests, I saw that I've got 20FPS. I've tried with a smaller scene (one box without texture or effects): same results.

Finally, after two days I've got a little idea but I don't understand how I can fix it: When objects are far, the framerate is ok, when there are near the camera, the framerate slow down. So, I think there is something with number of pixels draw on the screen (his resolution is 1920×1080).

**Where the problem should come from? I've already lost three days on this problem :/**

I'm using:

- Android NDK R10D
- OpenGL ES2
- A custom engine
- I've tried on the following devices: Nexus 4 (ARM), iPad 2 (PowerVR), Nexus 7 (ARM), iPhone 6 (PowerVR), Samsung Galaxy S2 (And the Wiko highway 4G, the only one with a slow framerate, and the most recent device I think)

Comment: Do you see similar behavior from other games and benchmarks on this device? e.g. is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epicgames.EpicCitadel&hl=en slow?

Comment: Yes, I've tried here is the results: Ultra high Quality - Average FPS : 26,9, Resolution : 1920*1080

Comment: Have you tried using systrace to identify where the time is being spent?  (Might need a rooted device to enable some of the more useful tags, unfortunately.)  http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html